# Resizing Screen affects Trigger in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on `Unity` game. It's replica of `Fruit Ninja` with awesome new features and updated graphics. Game is running fine but when I run it on full screen, Collision detection stops and `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(collision2D col)` function not called in most of cases. I should mention that collision is detected in some cases (not all).

P.S. Game is working super fine when not in full screen.

Comment: How did you set the Collision Detection of your rigidbodies? Discrete or Continous? It could be the issue.

Comment: collision is set to discrete

Comment: Try to change it: it's just a suggestion, I cannot be sure that it could solve but it can worth a try.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying .